# How to implement PLSQL Materialized view in hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have write a materialized view for full text search against `members`table:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW member_search_index AS
SELECT member.memberid,
member.firstname,
member.lastname,
...
to_tsvector((COALESCE(member.lastname, ' '::character varying))::text) AS document
FROM member
GROUP BY member.memberid;

CREATE INDEX idx_member_search ON member_search_index USING gin(document);
```

I have created entity and mapped it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MemberSearchIndex")
public class MemberSearch {
    @Id
    private long memberId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
...
}
```

And here's SQL call I am trying to make:

```
Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM member_search_index WHERE document @@ to_tsquery('doe:*')", MemberSearch.class);
```

In this example I have hard coded value that I am passing to query `doe` and the query is returning me 0 elements (it should return 1)

So:

1. Am I doing mapping correctly?
2. How to pass parameter to a native query like this? I tried like this `.setParameter(1, searchQuery)` but I got exception where `[1] couldn't be found`.

Comment: First thing I notice is your table name is wrong: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW member_search_index... then @Table(name = "MemberSearchIndex") - should be @Table(name = "member_search_index")

Comment: Thank you but I am still getting empty array from query result.

Comment: The error message you are getting probably means you are using the wrong syntax for parameters. There are named parameters e.g. :myName and anonymous numbered parameters which you are using. These are declared with a question mark (?) in your query.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM member_search_index WHERE document @@ to_tsquery('(?):*')"` throws me exception: `Parameter with that position [1] did not exist`. 
But besides this any idea why I am getting 0 rows return when there should be one with hard coded parameter?

Comment: After you fix the `@Table` name to mach the same name of your view, make sure to call `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW  member_search_index` from time to time. Otherwise, the view will still empty or has old data

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPQL query instead of native SQL. It will look like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("
    SELECT ms 
    FROM MemberSearch ms 
    WHERE SQL('to_tsvector(''english'', ?) @@ to_tsquery(''english'', ?)', ms.document, ?1)
    ");

query.setParameter(1, "'doe:*'");
query.getResultList();
```